# Dynamics CRM 2011 Once-off Bulk Update test records with random values

Tags: random, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, odata, linqpad

A thousand records are created in MS CRM Development Environment instance. A new field is required and is created by entity customization. We need random value in each record in that field. What are the supported ways to achive this?

Options I thought about are

1. Workflow (does not allow random value)
2. Bulk update (does not allow random value)
3. Bulk update with import from excel after adding a random value colum populated with =RAND(). Not sure if this will update existing records.
4. Writing an ODATA web resource html page to do this. (too fragile, long development and debug time and effort)
5. Using LinqPad 4 with CRM 2011 connector plugin to achieve the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution in LinqPad 4 with CRM connector took 10 minutes to process around 700 records.

```
//set up a random amount generator
var r = new Random();
//initialte with an arbitrary value
decimal amount = 13; 
//list all required records using linq
var ats = (from at in psm_assettypeSet
where at.psm_Amount.Equals(null)
select at).ToList();
//check count
ats.Count().Dump();
//check
(ats.First() as psm_assettype).psm_Amount.Dump();
//loop through
foreach (psm_assettype at in ats)
{
    //calculate amount
    amount = (decimal)r.Next(31);
    //check
    amount.Dump();
    //set amount, use XRM class properly
    at.psm_Amount = new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Money(amount);
    //update object in memory
    UpdateObject(at);
}
//bulk update all records
SaveChanges();
//check success
(ats.First() as psm_assettype).psm_Amount.Value.Dump();
```